# Outlook Add-In to Forward Mail as Attachment to Specific Address

Tags: outlook, outlook-web-addins

How do I add an Outlook ribbon button to send email to specific address? (Outlook Desktop and OWA)

Hi I'm currently having the use case of sending currently selected email to a specific address as an attachment. I wanted to develop the Web Add-In, which I currently have is the Visual Basic Macro that works pretty well (attached). Here is the use case for the ribbon add-in.

1. user got an email.
2. user open the email and find it suspicious.
3. user click the add-in button in a form of ribbon/may be others. (user do not need to enter or type anything else)
4. security team receive the email as an attachment.

I have done some research and said that it needs to work on Javascript for the latest Add-in to make this possible, but haven't known the function yet. Any help might be useful, thanks in advance!

```
Sub ReportPhishingEmail()

On Error Resume Next

Dim objItem As Outlook.MailItem

If Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count = 0 Then
   MsgBox ("No item selected")
   Exit Sub
End If

For Each objItem In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
    Set objMsg = objItem.Forward()
    With objMsg
        .Attachments.Add objItem, olEmbeddeditem
        .Subject = "Suspicious Email"
        .To = "security.team@gmail.com"
        .Body = "Please check whether it is a phishing email."
        .Send
        MsgBox ("Reporting Phising Mail Success.")
    End With

Next

Set objItem = Nothing
Set objMsg = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: I think you forgot to ask a question. There is no need to use Javascript to send an email, if that is the question.

Comment: @braX thank you for the reminder, i have edited the post. According to what I have been researching it is said that the latest add-in for Outlook uses Javascript on it.

Comment: Maybe you can show a link from what you mean? Maybe that's Office 365 only?

Comment: Sure, the add-in is like what is shown on this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/outlook-quickstart?tabs=visualstudio

Comment: I see. That's a different kind of Add-In than a VBA one. I have adjusted your tags so that your question will be in the right category. Those require Visual Studio and are written in VB.NET, not VBA.

Comment: Hey, For forwarding an item, you can use the Office.context.mailbox.item.itemId API to get the item ID and using REST make an API call. There is a concept [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/use-rest-api] page on calling REST APIs from an outlook add-in.

Comment: Why do you suggest using REST APIs? The Outlook REST APIs are deprecated. The Outlook REST endpoints will be fully decommissioned in November 2022. Use Microsoft Graph instead.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to develop and Outlook add-in, see [Build your first Outlook add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/outlook-quickstart?tabs=yeomangenerator) to get started quickly. From the add-in you can use the Graph API from which can do the required modifications, see [Overview of Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/overview) for more information.

The Outlook REST endpoints will be fully decommissioned in November 2022. So, it is not reasonable to rely on them any longer.